# How to set width and height to a master page variable from a web page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I need to set width and height to a master page variable from a web page running in ASP.NET.

Comment: is that "master page variable" a `javascript` or `asp.net` variable ?

Comment: thanks for reply balexandre .. it is a asp.net variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is JavaScript, you can access it same as in same page. but if you want to access any control in masterpage, `this.master`